# Developing a template library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm attempting to develop my own template library because I've looked at quite a few and they just do more than what I need. I'd like to be able to use assets and themes as well as modules into my template library.

The best one I've found was Phil Sturgeon's that he uses for PyroCMS. I'd like to develop something close to this but there's more than I need there.

My main thing is to find one that can handle themes, modules, and asset using.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? What is wrong with all libraries you tested? Be specific.

Comment: I guess I just like parts of all of them but don't know what I should add and what I shoudln't.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=codeigniter+template+libraries&oq=codeigniter+template+libraries

Comment: This is what we are using, but documentation is missing. It's a very good tempalte engine. http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show

Comment: @MDeSilva Did you have edit anything inside of it for it to work?

Comment: Nothing, If you want I can explain briefly, how to configure it.

Comment: If you could email me I'd appreciate it MDeSilva. So I can talk to you about this further. My email is kevin.smith754@yahoo.com.

Comment: It's just few steps, I'll post it here. Give me couple of mins, some what busy at the moment

Comment: I was hoping to talk to you privately about this if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy Template.php file to libraries folder from the package you downloaded.
2. Copy template.php file to config folder
3. Have you templates under views/templates
4. Edit the template.php (config file) as below

   ```
   //Default Template Configuration (adjust this or create your own)
   //Default template - This is the Main template

   $template['default']['template'] = 'template/template';
   $template['default']['regions'] = array('menu','content','title');

   $template['default']['parser'] = 'parser';
   $template['default']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
   $template['default']['parse_template'] = TRUE;



   //Login Template
   $template['login']['template'] = 'template/template_login';
   $template['login']['regions'] = array('content');

   $template['login']['parser'] = 'parser';
   $template['login']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
   $template['login']['parse_template'] = TRUE;
   ```

This is the basic configuration, If you want more info on how to send data from views, let me know

Comment: Could you email me so I can try and explain more.

Comment: This is the same library that I post in my answer, so in documentation you can read and understand easy.

Comment: I am in search of a template library that supports themes, modules, assets.

Comment: Anything I can do with it?

Comment: Yes you can have module specific templates with this library

Comment: what about themes and assets implemented though?

Comment: http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show. unfortunately documentation is missing his in blog. It was there few months back. http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/. you can ask him to publish it

Comment: Dang it. Still haven't troubles.

Answer (score 1):

One other idea for you is CodeIgniter Template.

Here you have the link:
http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

You can download, read the documentation and create your own template easly.

Comment: From what I can see in this though is themes aren't able to be used.

Comment: This is the library that allow you to create template for your application. You can read the documentation and see examples. I used it, and it works very good.

Comment: No. You need to have your own design.